# Can users vote to change the main site's user interface?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, design

I just visited [The Workplace.SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) site and fell in love with the background/UI. It's so sharp, clean and simple that I can see it appeal to users of all ages. However, the same cannot be said, IMHO, about the Math.SE background/UI (my favorite SE site). I am no web designer, but I would like to suggest a redesign to the entire Math.SE site.

My question is: Can we, the users, vote to redesign Math.SE (and Meta.Math.SE) and vote on a new design as well?

I love this site and see so much potential for it to become more attractive and user friendly. I will try to sketch what I see this site looking like and post as an update.

Comment: I am not in favor of big changes. Changing one thing here and there might be fine. Doing a complete revamp? No thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with the way it is now?  It's simple, no frills, practical.  Personally I would not like to see math.se redesigned to look "fancier."

Comment: I will add a link to the thread where the original design of the site was discussed: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/963/design-ideas-for-mathematics-site

Answer (score 9):

The design is done by one of the Stack Exchange designers, [currently those are Jin Yang and Stéphane Martin](http://stackexchange.com/about). While they take input from the community on the design, there is no formal voting.

The site designs are generally not changed completely, there is one exception that I know of and that was the Physics site. The original design used a white on black design that received a huge amount of criticism because it was hard to read for many users.

Stack Exchange does update minor parts of the design quietly, and it is not unlikely that something like this will happen at some point here.

SE does have a limited number of designers, and *a lot* of sites. They are very unlikely to focus their efforts on unnecessary design changes instead of new sites or small tweaks on existing sites. Apart from the considerable amount of time and money such a design costs, the community tends to get attached to the existing design and changing it would probably be controversial.

Comment: Worth mentioning that [Workplace.SE] (and some other recently graduated sites, like [Academia.SE]) are Stéphane Martin's designs. Older sites, including Math, were designed by Jin. The  approaches of two designers are visibly different.